# Generate Shared Access Signature (SAS) for one file using nodejs azure storage

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to generate a SAS for only one file in Azure Functions using Javascript. I'm using the following code to generate the SAS token:

```
function generateSAS(context, share, directory, file, permissions)
{
    var connString = process.env.AzureWebJobsDashboard;
    var FileService = azure.createFileService(connString);

    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setHours(expiryDate.getHours() + EXPIRY_TIME_HOURS);

     permissions = permissions || azure.FileUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ;

    var sharedAccessPolicy = { 
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: permissions,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };

    var sasToken = FileService.generateSharedAccessSignature(share, directory, file, sharedAccessPolicy)
    return sasToken;
}
```

However, the returned SAS token is valid for every file in the share. Is there any way I can limit the scope of the SAS within Javascript?

It's being called here:

```
module.exports = function (context, processQueueItem) {
    var fileName = processQueueItem.uID.toString() + randomGen() + ".png"

    var sas = generateSAS(context, share, directory, fileName, "r")
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code where you’re calling this function.

Comment: I don't see the `directory` variable being computed in your code. From where you're passing this parameter to `generateSAS`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw in my thought process @GauravMantri!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I generated the filename AFTER the generate SAS function call. This caused the function to generate a SAS for an empty file name, which provided authorization for all the files in the share.